# Unable to access entity data from a Role Id with Microsoft Identity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to access the information regarding schedule requests of a workshop  based on a Role Id.

The Schedule can be made by 2 Roles (Public and Internal) and I need to get the count in a timeframe based on a Role Id.

The problem is that the query generated is searching in the table "FROM [dbo].[IdentityUserRoles]" and I have tables called "AspNetUserRoles" so I get an error of "invalid object name [dbo].[IdentityUserRoles]".

My Schedule Request Model:

```
[Table("ScheduleRequests")]
public class ScheduleRequest
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User_Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

My AplicationUser Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

My Method to get the count:

```
public int GetScheduleRequestsByUserRoleByTimeframe(string roleId, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    dateTo = dateTo.AddDays(1);

    var dbContext = new DbContext();

    var query = dbContext.ScheduleRequests.Where(s => s.DateCreated >= dateFrom && s.DateCreated < dateTo);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleId))
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.User.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(roleId));
    }
    else
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.User_Id == null);
    }

    return query.Count();
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public DbContext() : base("DB") 
{
    // Tells Entity Framework that we will handle the creation of the database manually for all the projects in the solution
    Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // I have inserted this code base on a solution I found when I started to get Id Errors
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}

    public DbSet<ScheduleRequest> ScheduleRequests { get; set; }
}
```

I also have another Context create by the Microsoft Identity but I don't know for what it's used:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DB", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `DbContext` class from your codebase and use only `ApplicationDbContext` class as the context. Since you can add extra entities in `ApplicationDbContext`, you don't need another one in your application. Consider this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DB", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    // extra entities added here 
    public DbSet<ScheduleRequest> ScheduleRequests { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! Do I have to copy all the OnModelCreating code also?

Comment: No. When a class is inherited from `IdentityDbContext` its already had them.

Comment: Now I get the error "The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."

Comment: @Patrick It is normal. Because the database schema is changed. If you dose not have any important data in the database simply drop it. EF will create a new one for you. Or if cannot drop it. Consider enabling migration then.

Comment: I don't use Code First or Migrations, I have just use the code "Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);" and I think it solves the issue :) So if I understand, the problem was not inheriting from IdentityDbContext. Now I get "FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]"! :)) Problem Solved! Thank you very much!